How to use ontology catalog into protege
I am a new in this discussion group as a student of a CS undergraduate course.
I had a problem when I used catalog-001.xml which was included in a directory where I downloaded a bunch of OWL files.
I am wondering what is the purpose of using catalog-001.xml and how to use it.
(I tried to find out by searching on the internet but there is not much information about it.)
Since the program consists of 7 .OWL files with only one catalog-001.xml file, I assume that the catalog-v001.xml file
helps to import all 7 .OWL files to form a single tree structure in Protege.
Am I right?
Please give me some feedback on this problem
I am testing multiple OWL files in a directory. When I execute context.owl, all the OWL files in the directory should load, but they are not, which is causing difficulties.

In essence you are absolutely right. The purpose of file catalog-001.xml in Protégé is to act as an ontology library that stores mappings between ontology IRIs and the local file paths where those ontologies are stored on your file system. It allows Protégé to quickly locate and load imported ontologies without needing to repeatedly search or download them from the Web.
When you import ontologies into a Protégé project, only the IRI of the imported ontology is saved (see here). If Protégé can't find the ontology using the IRI (e.g., because it's a local file and not a web URL), it will consult catalog-001.xml to find the corresponding local file path. This speeds up the process substantially, especially when working with many ontologies.
If, however, catalog-001.xml is missing the necessary mappings, Protégé won't be able to load the imported ontologies.
Overall, it's not good practice to tamper with the catalog file anyways.
